# Separate on each sed match

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed to return the lines between two different patterns `[(1) <Directory>, (2) </Directory>]`. For the given input file, there are multiple matches for sed, and I was wondering if it is possible to pipe each individual match.

What I'm trying to do basically:
    `sed -n "/ddd/,/</ddd>p" < input.conf | grep Options`

```
...
ddd    Start of Match group #1
eee
fff
/ddd   End of Match group #1
...
ddd    Start of Match group #2
iii
yyy
/ddd   End of Match group #2
```

I want to check to see if each match group contains the pattern fff.

Answer (score 0):

Given the complex set of requirements, awk is a better match for this problem.

An equivalent to the sed printing from start to end is (in awk):

```
$ awk '/^ddd/{p=1};p;/^[/]ddd/{p=0}' file
ddd    Start of Match group #1
eee
fff
/ddd   End of Match group #1
ddd    Start of Match group #2
iii
yyy
/ddd   End of Match group #2
```

Using the `^` ensures that the amtch is at the start of the line, and the `[\]` will match only a `\` also at the beggining of the line.

Switching the tests, we can remove the start and end lines:

```
$ awk '/^[/]ddd/{p=0};p;/^ddd/{p=1}' file
eee
fff
iii
yyy
```

All that remains to test is if (while inside one range) there is any line with `fff`. That could be done with:

```
awk ' /^[/]ddd/{p=0;if(found==0){print NR};found=0};
      p&&($0~/fff/){found=1};
      /^ddd/{p=1}
    ' file
```

Which will print the line number (NR) of the last line of the group that did not contain `fff` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -n '/ddd/ {:L; N; /\/ddd/!bL; /fff/ !{p; =;} }' file
```

When encountering `ddd`, it collects the lines up to `/ddd` in pattern space, then tests for `fff` and, if absent, prints the group and the group's last line number.